# Eclipse IDE Pydev Import Errors

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am having issues in trying to get the Pydev install in Eclipse to recognise my installed modules such as Beautiful Soup. Within the Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter I have used the Auto Config (which didn't work) and also tried telling Pydev where the Python interpreter is manually. I am on Macosx running Python 2.7.2.

If I import BeautifulSoup within IDLE it works fine. What Eclipse doesn't seem to do is load the site-packages. Going back to the auto-config it loads user/bin/python as the Interpreter and my system path consists of these: [image: pydev system PYTHONPATH]

I have tried reinstalling Eclipse, following several tutorials on Youtube and also following other peoples solutions with no success. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding the site-packages folder to the pydev pythonpath using "New Folder"? I'm not sure how it works in osx but this is a sometimes useful method in windows

Comment: Yes I tried that but the site-packages folder doesn't show within the Finder window that appears! Thoroughly confused! I have also tried installing the interpreter from: Libray/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python.2.7 and that also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

When you press the auto-config or add a new interpreter, it'll show a dialog with all the paths it found to be in the PYTHONPATH, but some are not checked by default (it only leaves checked what it believes to be common to all projects -- i.e.: under the python installation), so, try checking if the site-packages appear at that dialog and check it if it's there...

Also, I remember that MacOS has an issue in which it doesn't ship source files for the libraries, so, that may be an issue too (in which case I'd recommend installing a Python version from python.org instead of using the one that comes pre-installed in MacOS).

Comment: Managed to get it working, though not entirely sure how. Cheers everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try to change proxy settings of eclipse.

Select Active Provider to "Manual". Set HTTP/HTTPS proxy. Clear SOCKS proxy if this is set.(select SOCKS proxy raw and click "Clear" button) Restart Eclipse to apply these settings.